# Why is it faster to run the SQL in the loop and not outside

Tags: php, laravel

i try to improve performance in my code:

example code:

```
for($i = 0; $i<= 10000; $i++){


 //do stuff

 $test = DB::table('test')->where('test2', $i)->get();

 //do stuff

}
```

this example code runs: 3 seconds.

Now i tried to optimize the code with setting the sql outside the loop like:

```
$test = DB::table('test')->whereBetween('test2', [ 0, 10000 ])->get();

for($i = 0; $i<= 10000; $i++){


 //do stuff

 $test = $test->where('test2',$i);

 //do stuff

}
```

but this code runs: 5 seconds. Are the 10000 sqls really faster then one sql and 10000 collection wheres?

i log it with:         `Log::info(round(microtime(true) * 1000));`

Comment: well if your benchmark is correct, this result is just mindblow :O.

its just doesnt make any sense if youre running 10k query and its faster than 1 query

Comment: I've a sneaking suspicion it would largely depend on indexes - or a lack thereof. _Generally_ speaking, lots of small queries _can_ be faster than a single complex query (though this query probably isn't complex either way); so it sort of depends on what's _really_ in the SQL and whether that's using the indexes (if there are any).

Comment: Your queries are not equal. First one does not have `->whereBetween('test2', [ 0, 10000 ])` condition. That's why it's slower

Comment: @Justinas because the first one doesnt need between you didnt get it

Comment: Why does the second one still contain `$test = $test->where('test2',$i);` ...? Is that not throwing errors to begin with, since you used `->get()` on the query?

Comment: @CBroe the second where is the collection function

Comment: If you `order` your query by test2, then you don't have to keep on doing the `$test->where('test2',$i);`, just loop over the result and you will have them in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are, in this case, running 1 query and instantiating a collection with 10k objects looping that entire collection 10k times to find a single entity.

Vs.

Sending 10k queries to a hyper-optimised, indexed database solution built for that exact purpose and getting back a single entity.

On top of that, your queries aren't looking at the same thing, so naturally, it will be even slower.

Simply asking a database solution to give entries `WHERE X = Y` is always going to be faster than asking the same in the format of `WHERE X > 0 AND X < 10000`

The slow down comes from instantiating a collection of 10000 entities and looping them repeatedly 10000 times while trying to find where `test2 = id`.

Whereas with SQL, you can find that much faster than you can by looping it in PHP.

---

In short, you could rephrase your question:

> is it faster to query a database 10k times or to loop a collection of 10k entities 10k times in plain PHP while comparing the value of each record to an ID?

To which SQL becomes the more obvious answer.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer explains it very well, wanted just to add that you can reduce complexity, so instead of `loop a collection of 10k entities 10k times` you can loop once by using the `keyBy`:

```
$test = DB::table('test')->whereBetween('test2', [ 0, 10000 ])->get();
$indexedCollection = $test->keyBy('test2');

for($i = 0; $i<= 10000; $i++){
    //do stuff

    $test = $indexedCollection[$i] ?? null;

    //do stuff

}
```

Comment: this is great, but  what if test2 is not unique so $test is a array ?

Comment: @Elias you can use `groupBy()` instead of `keyBy()`.